# Is there a way with CSS and/or Javascript to compensate for different default font sizes on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

When designing mobile sites, I design based on the default font size for the mobile device (iOS or Android). When someone selects a large default font size in their phone settings (not the zoom in the browser), it breaks the design. Is there a way I can target those devices with a CSS media query or Javascript/jQuery to readjust the font sizes so they look right?

Answer (score 0):

No. The mobile settings override the fonts in CSS. Otherwise, it would be very frustrating for the user if they wanted to increase the sizes but can't.